# Query based on sub-entity type

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Assume I have a entity that looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Garage {
    ...
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String garageId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "garage")
    private Set<Vehicle> vehicles = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

The vehicle entity looks like following:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Vehicle{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
  private Long id;


  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "garage_id", referencedColumnName = "garageId", nullable = false)
  private Garage garage;
```

I have two sub entitys that inherit from vehicle, they may look like following

```
@Entity
public class Truck extends Vehicle {
   ...
}


@Entity
public class Motorcycle extends Vehicle {
   ...
}
```

In Spring Data JPA, how would I query for Garages that contains a Motorcycle? Also throwing out another question, is there any way to enforce that the Garage may only have one of each sub-entity? (A garage may contain 1 truck + 1 motorcycle but not more then 1 of the specific vehicle)

Comment: So are we to assume that trucks and motorcycles are being stored in the same database table?  If so, what is the column in this table that specifies the vehicle type?

Comment: Since the inheritance type is `TABLE_PER_CLASS`, different types of vehicles are being stored in separate tables. The easiest way would therefore be to put the query on the `VehicleRepository` as `List<Garage> findAllDistinctGarages()`. However, this does not seem to work due to a type resolution problem with Spring Data. I have raised [an issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1046) with the Spring Data team to get their perspective on how this can be resolved. A sample project is available on [Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/41701838).

Comment: There was a mistake in my sample project. Take a look now. `List<Garage> findAllDistinctGarages()` on `VehicleRepository` actually works.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a Repository for Garage, in that interface, define the following method.

```
List<Garage> findByVehicles(Vehicle vehicle);
```

Then, assuming that you have an instance of Motorcyle called motorcycle, you can call this with

```
List<Garage> garagesWithMotorcyle = garageRepository.findByVehicles(motorcyle);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without needing a instance of the sub-entity? Feels kinda unnecessary having to initialize a instance that I wont use after performing my query.

Comment: Without the instance, how will you have the data to search by?  I'll just go out on a limb and guess that you have the vehicle ID, which would be the minimum amount of information you would need to query a Garage with.  Add this method to your repository  `List<Garaga> findByVehiclesId(Long id);`